# How to set GMail custom star color in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Running an Apps Script on my GMail Inbox to help me prioritize my emails (NOTE: the built-in prioritization for GMail is not working after training it for months, it still gets things backwards all the time, so I turned it off - so please don't suggest I do that)

I have a loop that goes through all the relevant messages, and sets each message to a `GmailMessage` class variable called `thisMessage`. I can set a "star" using `thisMessage.star()` and I can remove a "star" using `thisMessage.unstar()`. However, I would prefer to be able to use the different, built-in custom start shapes and colors (e.g. `red-bang`, `yellow-bang`, `green-check`). From other questions here, I have figured out how to search for them and bring up emails with particular stars. However, I have to manually set them in the GMail app. I want them to be automatically set under some conditions in my script (Note: I'm currently using labels in place of the stars, but I would like to not clutter up my label list in the app)

How do you actually set one of these custom stars in a given message in Apps Script?

Comment: See this article [GmailApp.starMessage(message)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#starMessage(GmailMessage))

Comment: You won't be able to do anything more than star/unstar with Apps Script :(

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is a feature **only available in the Web UI**. Star type cannot be changed either with Apps Script or the API in general. Even the mobile Gmail app doesn't support the different types.

A few hints to this are that the [message object](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages) doesn't have any star-related attributes. Also, if you check the [`messages.get`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get) representation of an email you will notice that the starred status of an email is defined by `"labelIds":["STARRED"]`, but you can change the star type in the UI and the label will still be the same and there are no other attributes changed.

There are multiple threads in Google's issue tracker requesting this, such as [this one](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/36758847) or [this one](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/76028367) and also [this one](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36755157). They've been open for a while so it doesn't look like Google is prioritizing this feature, so the best you can do for now is to +1 these threads and hope they see that there's more user demand for it. If you really must automate these differentiations between important emails the closest you'll get is to use [labels](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels), which do have Apps Script [methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-label).